# Custom CameraView bugs whole app when integrating it into my app

Tags: swiftui, uikit, avfoundation

I have a custom camera view which uses UIKit to capture pictures and store it in a CameraViewModel in my SwiftUI project. The CameraPreview is what acts as the view Finder for my camera view and uses AVFoundation:

```swift
struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    class VideoPreviewView: UIView {
        override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
             AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
        }
        
        var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
            return layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
        }
    }
    
    let session: AVCaptureSession
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> VideoPreviewView {
        let view = VideoPreviewView()
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        view.videoPreviewLayer.cornerRadius = 0
        view.videoPreviewLayer.session = session
        view.videoPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait

        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: VideoPreviewView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

and the I use this in my CameraView.swift body as such

```swift
  @StateObject var model = CameraViewModel()
  
  @State var currentZoomFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
  @Binding var showCameraView: Bool
  
  // MARK: [main body starts here]
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { reader in
      ZStack {
        // This black background lies behind everything. 
        Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
        CameraPreview(session: model.session)
          .onAppear {
            model.configure()
          }
          .alert(isPresented: $model.showAlertError, content: {
            Alert(title: Text(model.alertError.title), message: Text(model.alertError.message), dismissButton: .default(Text(model.alertError.primaryButtonTitle), action: {
              model.alertError.primaryAction?()
            }))
          })
          .overlay(
            Group {
              if model.willCapturePhoto {
                Color.black
              }
            }
          )
          .scaledToFill()
          .ignoresSafeArea()
          .frame(width: reader.size.width,height: reader.size.height )
        //            .animation(.easeInOut)
        
        VStack {
          HStack {
            Button {
              //
            } label: {
              Image(systemName: "xmark")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .tint(.white)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing)
            
            Spacer()
            
            flashButton
          }
          
          HStack {
            capturedPhotoThumbnail
            
            Spacer()
            
            captureButton
            
            Spacer()
            
            flipCameraButton
            
          }
          .padding([.horizontal, .bottom], 20)
          .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
        }
      } // [ZStack Ends Here]
    } // [Geometry Reader Ends here]
  } // [Main Body Ends here]
```

I wish to open the camera View when someone presses a button somewhere on my app, like so

```swift
@State var showCamera: Bool = false 
var body: some View { 
   mainTabView
     .overlay {
        CameraView(showCamera: $showCamera) 
     }
}
```

But when I do this in my app, no matter where I put the camera overlay, it stays open and the close button does nothing to close the camera view either. I'm pretty sure this is my fundamental lack of how views are constructed in UIKit and how the UIViewRepresentable works but I'd like some help regardless on how I'd achieve the desired effect. Also, any resources to understand how this works would also be greatly appreciated. Thank you.